# Eloquent relationship property access

Tags: laravel

Cant seem to figure out the probleme here, getting error - `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object`

User DB

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('lastname');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('phone');
        $table->boolean('isAdmin')->default(0);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Sludinajums DB

```
 Schema::create('sludinajums', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('logo');
        $table->string('nosaukums');
        $table->string('regnr');
        $table->string('text');
        $table->string('atrasanasVieta');
        $table->string('adrese');
        $table->integer('telefons');
        $table->string('epasts');
        $table->integer('profesija_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('profesija_id')->references('id')->on('profesijas')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('lietotajs_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('lietotajs_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

User model function

```
public function sludinajums()
{
    return $this->hasOne(sludinajums::class,'lietotajs_id');
}
```

Sludinajums model function

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Here is my controller function

```
public function sludinajuma_skats($id){
    $slud = sludinajums::where('id',$id)->with('user')->get();

    return view('views.sludinajums', compact('slud'));
}
```

And in my view im trying to access name attribute from User table.

```
{{dd($sl->user->name)}}
```

Comment: What's `$sl` in your view?

Comment: `@foreach ($slud as $sl)` just a foreach to print values

Comment: Apparently not every `$sl` has a `user`.

Answer (score 0):

try this for Sludinajums model function

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User','lietotajs_id');
}
```